# How to Control Chrome and Edge updates with intune

Tags: windows, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, intune

I know how to set chrome to automatically update Autopilot devices to the chrome stable channel.
However, there does not seem to be a method to control the update version, for example update to X not Y. I want control over the automatic update is there a variable that can be used?

Is there a method to implement this?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Is [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69799262/how-to-control-chrome-and-edge-updates-with-intune/69805108#69805108) helpful to deal with the issue? Please let me know if there is anything that I can help here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use group policies to control browser update version. Using Edge for example, you can use [Target version override](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/microsoft-edge-update-policies#target-version-override) policy to set the specific update version.

> When this policy is enabled, and auto-update is enabled, Microsoft Edge will be updated to the version specified by this policy value.

GP path: `Administrative Templates/Microsoft Edge Update/Applications/Microsoft Edge`

About how to configure Edge update policy settings in Microsoft Intune, you can refer to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/configuration/administrative-templates-configure-edge?bc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2FDeployEdge%2Fbreadcrumb%2Ftoc.json&toc=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2FDeployEdge%2Ftoc.json).